# Two errors prevent search function from working - Android

Tags: android

I am developing a search function (which searches a table in MySQL database) but it is not working. Whenever I type a value in the search bar, toast shows "searching then no results display. I have the main activity where `setOnQueryTextListener` exists.

```
public class FindSkill extends AppCompatActivity {
SearchView searchView;
ListView listView;
ImageView noData, noNetwork;
String urlAdress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.find_skill);


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchList);
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    noData = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nodata);
    noNetwork = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nonetwork);
    urlAdress = "http://skillsexchangecyprus.com/SEC/ss.php";



  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            SenderReceiver sr = new SenderReceiver(FindSkill.this, urlAdress,listView, query,noData,noNetwork);
            sr.execute();
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            SenderReceiver sr = new SenderReceiver(FindSkill.this, urlAdress, listView, query, noData, noNetwork);
            sr.execute();
            return false;
        }});}
}
```

and here is the code of **SenderReceiver class**:

```
public class SenderReceiver extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
Context ctx;
String urlAdress;
String query;
ListView listView;
ImageView noData, noNetwork;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;



public SenderReceiver(Context ctx, String urlAdress, ListView listView, String query, ImageView... imageViews){
    this.ctx=ctx;
    this.urlAdress=urlAdress;
    this.listView=listView;
    this.query=query;
    this.noData=imageViews[0];
    this.noNetwork=imageViews[1];
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Search");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Searching... Please Wait!");
    progressDialog.show();
}



@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.sendAndReceive();
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    progressDialog.dismiss();

    //Reset listView
    listView.setAdapter(null);

    if ( s!= null ){

        if(! s.contains("null")) {
            if(s.length() > 0){
                Parser parser = new Parser(ctx,s,listView);
                parser.execute();
            }
        }else {
            noNetwork.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            noData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } //data = "[{\"post_title\":\"title1\"},{\"post_title\":\"title2\"}]";

    }else {
        noNetwork.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        noData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}

private String sendAndReceive(){

    HttpURLConnection connection = Connector.connection(urlAdress);


    if (connection == null){
        return null;
    }

    try {
        String urlParameters = "query=art";
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.write(urlParameters);
        outputStream.flush();
       // OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter((outputStream));// write it to the network
        bufferedWriter.write(new DataBackager(query).packageData());
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();

        //response
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        //decode
        if (responseCode == connection.HTTP_OK){
            //return data
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            //read data
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(( new InputStreamReader(inputStream)));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            if (bufferedReader != null){
                while ((line= bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    response.append(line + "\n");
                }
            }else {
                return null;
            }

            return response.toString();

        }else{
            return  String.valueOf(responseCode);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

**Parser class:**

```
public class Parser extends AsyncTask <Void, Void,Integer> {
Context ctx;
ListView listView;
String data;
ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();


public Parser(Context ctx, String data, ListView listView) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.data=data;
    this.listView = listView;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.parse();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
    super.onPostExecute(integer);

    if (integer == 1) {
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Unable to Parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


private int parse() {


    try {
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);
        JSONObject jo = null;

        titles.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = jo.getString("post_title");
            titles.add(title);
        }
        return 1;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

What the log shows when typing in the search bar:

```
03-22 20:19:10.881 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{8d1f108 V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
03-22 20:19:10.891 27300-28889/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-22 20:19:10.891 27300-28889/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-22 20:19:10.891 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
03-22 20:19:10.941 27300-27456/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1592x909]-format:1
03-22 20:19:10.961 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
03-22 20:19:10.991 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
03-22 20:19:11.671 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
03-22 20:19:11.701 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
03-22 20:19:15.261 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{89ca702 V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
03-22 20:19:15.271 27300-28989/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-22 20:19:15.271 27300-28989/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-22 20:19:15.281 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
03-22 20:19:15.331 27300-27456/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1592x909]-format:1
03-22 20:19:15.341 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
03-22 20:19:15.351 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
03-22 20:19:15.451 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
03-22 20:19:15.481 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
03-22 20:19:15.991 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
03-22 20:19:16.031 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
03-22 20:19:16.151 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1128) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1128) or=1
03-22 20:19:16.161 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
03-22 20:19:45.241 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.431 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.531 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.531 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.531 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.671 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.691 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{77cc7ba token=android.os.BinderProxy@39d6639 {com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange.FindSkill}} show : true
03-22 20:19:45.691 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.701 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.701 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.711 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.711 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:46.101 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
```

PS: PHP code is 100% working because I tried it with the database and it showed the desired results. And I made a search for the most obvious errors in the log `E/ViewRootImpl: mStopped=false mHasWindowFocus=false mPausedForTransition=false and sendUserActionEvent() mView == null`, but couldn't figure out to which part of the code they're related

Comment: filtering the `ListView` is done as follows: `adapter.getFilter().filter(query)` - do not use any `AsyncTask` for that (or even two of them)

Comment: In which part you mean?

Comment: `onQueryTextChange` - where you are typing something in your `SearchView`

Comment: please help me understand you. Didn't get your point yet
where does this should be used: "adapter.getFilter().filter(query)"

Comment: did you read my previous comment? i wrote: `onQueryTextChange` - this is the method that is called when you type anything in your `SearchView`

Comment: I edited onQueryTextChange to be: 
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                Parser par = new Parser(FindSkill.this, data, listView);
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false; 
but it causes the app to stop.